# dynamic feature flag in spring

Tags: java, spring, toggle

my web app has a method `test` which get invoked by a cronjob every two minutes, and I like to be able dynamically switching between `solution a` and `solution b` with some feature flag without deploying it each time.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateService = "120000")
public void test(){
if(conditionA()) {
  // do solution A
  } else {
  // do solution B
  }
}
```

I was thinking to use a cookie for this purpose but it only works on the session that I have opened, and still, the other solution could be invoked by other sessions.

is there any way that I can enforce only one solution running in production and dynamically swapping them without releasing them each time?

**Update:**
Jonathan Johx answer is correct, and I add some clarification here

to update the value of the properties you need first to `POST` your key/value in `x-www-form-urlencoded` format to `\actuator\env`, then force reloading it with by post an empty payload to the `\actuator\refresh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might use [@RefreshScope](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope) annotation to refresh properties:

**1.-** Add `@RefreshScope` on class

```
@RefreshScope
@Component
public class Test { 

    @Value("${conditional.istrue}")
    private boolean conditional;

    @Scheduled(fixedRateService = "120000")
    public void test(){
    if(conditional) {
      // do solution A
      } else {
      // do solution B
      }
    }   
}
```

**2.-** Add flag property and allow exposure the endpoint `/refresh` in order to refresh new properties.

application.properties

```
  conditional.istrue=true
  management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

**3.-** Once the application.properties is modified for example:

```
  conditional.istrue=false
```

Then you can `refresh` configurations injected doing:

```
 curl localhost:8080/actuator/refresh -d {} -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

**REFERENCES**
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

Comment: thanks, I guess this only work if you have external config and commit to it?

Comment: Not necessarily, because you can have an application.properties in your project resources then you don't need to have external config of some service if that is the case.

Comment: I see, but when I try to update the `conditional.istrue` from default true to false by `curl localhost:8080/actuator/refresh -d { conditional.istrue=false
} -H "Content-Type: application/json"` command, the value is not changing, am I missing any step ?

Comment: you don't need to pass in { } the condition.isTrue=false, you need to set from application.properties @rawData

Comment: What happens if the value is updated/refreshed at the same time than a read? isn't this a race condition ?